# Find the largest value in the chart Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

I am using the syncfusion_flutter_charts package to create a chart. I need to make a value check and display the column with the largest value in red. Tell me how to put a condition / loop correctly in order to check the values ​​of the y-axis and recolor the larger value in red? I will be grateful for help.

**chart**

```
class ChartWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const ChartWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<ChartWidget> createState() => _ChartWidget();
}

class _ChartWidget extends State<ChartWidget> {
  late List<_ChartData> data;
  TooltipBehavior? _tooltipBehavior;

  @override
  void initState() {
    data = [
      _ChartData('6:00', 18),
      _ChartData('7:00', 11),
      _ChartData('8:00', 14),
      _ChartData('9:00', 5),
      _ChartData('10:00', 16),
      _ChartData('11:00', 13),
      _ChartData('12:00', 15),
      _ChartData('13:00', 1),
      _ChartData('14:00', 2),
      _ChartData('15:00', 15),
      _ChartData('16:00', 18),
      _ChartData('17:00', 11),
      _ChartData('18:00', 14),
      _ChartData('19:00', 5),
      _ChartData('20:00', 16),
      _ChartData('21:00', 13),
      _ChartData('22:00', 20),
      _ChartData('23:00', 1),
      _ChartData('24:00', 2),
    ];
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _buildColumnChart();
  }

  SfCartesianChart _buildColumnChart() {
    return SfCartesianChart(
      plotAreaBorderWidth: 0,
      zoomPanBehavior: ZoomPanBehavior(enablePanning: true),
      primaryXAxis: CategoryAxis(
        interval: 3,
        visibleMaximum: 16,
        axisLine: const AxisLine(width: 0),
        labelStyle: constants.Styles.xxTinyLtStdTextStyleWhite,
        majorTickLines: const MajorTickLines(width: 0),
        majorGridLines: const MajorGridLines(width: 0),
      ),
      primaryYAxis:
          NumericAxis(isVisible: false, minimum: 0, maximum: 20, interval: 1),
      tooltipBehavior: _tooltipBehavior,
      series: <ChartSeries<_ChartData, String>>[
        ColumnSeries<_ChartData, String>(
            dataSource: data,
            color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
            borderColor: constants.Colors.greyChart,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4),
            xValueMapper: (_ChartData data, _) => data.x,
            yValueMapper: (_ChartData data, _) => data.y,
            name: 'Test'),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class _ChartData {
  _ChartData(this.x, this.y);

  final String x;
  final double y;
}
```

**This is the desired result**

[image]

Comment: Which value to make comparison on?  final String x or
  final double y?

If it is y, the largest value is 20 @ index position 16 in data list. Showed in photo otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [pointColorMapper](https://pub.dev/documentation/syncfusion_flutter_charts/latest/charts/CartesianSeries/pointColorMapper.html)

find the max value

```
 double maxValue = 0;


    //loop list of _ChartData to compare its y value and find the max
    data.forEach((data){
      if(data.y>maxValue) {
      maxValue = data.y;
     }
   });
```

Then instead of using color use pointColorMapper

```
      //Instead of 
      color: constants.Colors.greyMiddle,

      //use
      pointColorMapper: (_ChartData data,_){ 
          if(data.y == maxValue){
            return constants.Colors.YourRedColor;
          }
          else{
            return constants.Colors.greyMiddle;
          }
      },
```

Answer (score 1):

This was the code I worked with, the final output being 'largest value is 20 and index: 16'

```
void main() {


  var data = [
      _ChartData('6:00', 18),
      _ChartData('7:00', 11),
      _ChartData('8:00', 14),
      _ChartData('9:00', 5),
      _ChartData('10:00', 16),
      _ChartData('11:00', 13),
      _ChartData('12:00', 15),
      _ChartData('13:00', 1),
      _ChartData('14:00', 2),
      _ChartData('15:00', 15),
      _ChartData('16:00', 18),
      _ChartData('17:00', 11),
      _ChartData('18:00', 14),
      _ChartData('19:00', 5),
      _ChartData('20:00', 16),
      _ChartData('21:00', 13),
      _ChartData('22:00', 20),
      _ChartData('23:00', 1),
      _ChartData('24:00', 2),
    ];


  double largest_val = 0.0;
  int largest_val_index = 0;


  for(int k = 0; k < data.length; k++){
    if(data[k].y >largest_val){
      largest_val = data[k].y;
      largest_val_index = k;
    }    
  }

  print('largest value is ${largest_val} and index: ${largest_val_index}');

}

class _ChartData {
  _ChartData(this.x, this.y);

  final String x;
  final double y;
}
```

variable `largest_val_index` can be used to get the index in list `data` while `largest_val` gives the largest value.

void main() should be removed while execution.

Answer (score 1):

To use a specific color to a point, you can make use of pointColorMapper property. Find the maximum y-value from your data source and based on that you can apply color to each point using the pointColorMapper. We have attached the code below

```
late double yMaximum = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    data = [
      //Your data
    ];
    getMax(data);
    super.initState();
  }

  void getMax(List<_ChartData> data) {
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
      if (data[i].y > yMaximum) yMaximum = data[i].y;
  }


    SfCartesianChart(
          //Other properties
           series: <ChartSeries<_ChartData, String>>[
            ColumnSeries<_ChartData, String>(
                pointColorMapper: (_ChartData data, _) =>
                    data.y == yMaximum ? constants.Colors.YourRedColor : constants.Colors.greyMiddle,
            ),
          ],
        )
```

Already we have a demo sample to apply the color based on the y-value using the pointColorMapper, which can be found below.

[Demo](https://flutter.syncfusion.com/#/cartesian-charts/series-features/point-color-mapping)
[UG](https://help.syncfusion.com/flutter/cartesian-charts/series-customization#color-mapping-for-data-points)